# Unable to run rust playground locally

Tags: rust

I am trying to run rust playground locally : https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground
The instructions are to

- cd to `ui/frontend` && `yarn` to build the frontend
- cd ../ && cargo run to run the server.

However , when i navigate to `127.0.0.1:5000` on my browser , the page returns on 404.  This is quite confusing as looking at the code , the default port is `5000` and its running on `127.0.0.1`

```
   Compiling octocrab v0.16.0
   Compiling ui v0.1.0 (/Users/Code/rust/rust-playground/ui)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 58.76s
     Running `target/debug/ui`
```

I would appreciate any guidance on this

Comment: Did you try opening a browser at that address?

Comment: yes i have and it it shows the page as not found aka 404@ChayimFriedman

Comment: *"when i follow the instruction"* - Please show us what exactly that means. I'm sure the instructions work for other people, otherwise they wouldn't exist. Please show us the exact steps you took.

Comment: apologies @Finomnis. Ive added the steps to my question

Comment: probably the ui build fails, may you include logs of this step ?